# Django: Cursor closes before expected

Tags: django

I have a view with a get function. In there I open a cursor connection and put the cursor in my context for use in my template tags. I figured since the template renders and then the get completes, the safest place to close my cursor would be at the end of my get.

However, in trying to use the cursor in my template tag, it tells me "cursor already closed".

Can someone explain to me what's happening?

Comment: Why are you messing with cursors at all? Use the ORM, with `raw` method if you really really need to use SQL.

Comment: Can't use the ORM/raw because I'm reading from a table I've created dynamically. 

I basically create a dynamic table, do a bunch of stuff on it, then wanna drop/close it after page render is done (hence, end of get before returning the response... if only it actually worked)

Comment: Isn't it possible/suitable to get all data from DB in view?

Answer (score 0):

My local database expert told me I don't have to close my cursor, django'll do it when my view object is destroyed. So there.